# Why is there "Asked: today"?

Tags: support, design

I just noticed new UI and that new row under question title:

---

[image]

---

The only useful thing for me is "Viewed", especially on my own posts.

Why there is "Asked" if I can see time of post at bottom? I am anyway will be checking it at bottom, because it's near to "edited" and other important controls and this is where am I usually after reading question to the end anyway.

Comment: I think this information was previously shown a *bit* less prominently in a box in the upper right, wasn't it?

Comment: It's a new bar but not new information - it used to be on the side before.

Comment: I like the change. This might not be an optimal design, but it looks alright, and is probably a lot more flexible than the old one. When it was in the sidebar, this information would be pushed down below the post on a mobile screen. That frequently irritated me. Now it's kept near the top, where I can actually find it when I want to the most recently-active post. I see what you mean about Asked being duplicated, but it's easier to find here with the other information than in the middle of a potentially long page to scroll through.

Comment: The position of the information is ok, but why is it more coarsly presented there than below? I would consider it more informative and consistent to show the same information as below ("1 hour ago" in this case)

Comment: It's a whole network change, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331349/299295) is another complainer.

Comment: You aren't considering that there are different types of users. Consider coming to post from a search engine. Age & activity have more relevance then

Comment: @charlietfl, not for me. As I said, I'll be checking dates at the bottom of question and edit date is more important imho. Also I am not used to "Active" link, scrolling all the way down through all answers is my way. Search engines is interesting argument, just checked what google shows, it's rather confusing: for some questions it shows "Asked" at the bottom, for others - as datetime before question text, for most - no dates at all, so loading page and looking on top of it is a good reason why there should be date.. hmm.

Answer (score 2):

> The only useful thing for me is "Viewed", especially on my own posts.

Well, others might find it useful so I see no reason to outright discard it.

> Why there is "Asked" if I can see time of post at bottom?

All the information you see there already existed previously, it was just positioned awkwardly to the right hand side. It's a lot more convenient now than before because everything is compact and in one block. You can glance across the title and then see the stats directly beneath it.

Comment: This is, at best, secondary meta information, and positioned far too prominently right at the top after the title. I really don't need to see this every single time I read a question.

Comment: The way it was before was much better

Comment: there's a bug though. there supposed to be a popup with the exact data for all three when I hover above them, but there's none for the "views" now. And if the number is e.g. "2k", there's no way to see the exact figure. There was the popup before, on the side, I'm sure of it.

Comment: @WillNess make a separate post regarding it.

Comment: it's already being discussed. (sorry, wrong link).

Comment: @WillNess thanks for the link (even the wrong one would be helpful to see what's  going on).

Comment: I meant [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331366/172601).